# How could I add data by text in Datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datatable with 3 columns and i made it in sql database connect. I created a blank row in datagridview by click button. How could I add text in this row and save in databaseve , What i have to do next?. This is add row code :

```
 private void Btn_newf2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from MSTBackupCtr_Folder";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        DataRow Newrow = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(Newrow);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = ("No");
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = ("Active_Flag");
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = ("Folder");


    }
```

Comment: Add values to the `Newrow` and at last call `da.Update(dt)`

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

```
foreach (GridViewRow r in grdtemp.Rows)
{
   TextBox No = (TextBox)r.FindControl("txtNo");
   TextBox ActiveFlag = (TextBox)r.FindControl("txtActvFlag");
   TextBox Folder = (TextBox)r.FindControl("txtFolder");


   int j = Bll.DbClass("insert into MSTBackupCtr_Folder
   values(no,flag,folder) values ('"+No.Text+"','"+ActiveFlag.Text+"','"+Folder.Text+"')");
//BLL.DbClass is my custom class for Data insertion 

}
```